# TFS build server 2015 stuck on waiting for an available agent

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, build-server

I am using TFS build server 2015 and I'm trying to run a build but the build always stuck on 
`waiting for an available agent` for 2-3 minutes and then fails.
I tried to download the **log.zip** but its empty.

[image: waiting for an available agent]

When I run the agent from cmd the next message appears:

> The Agent failed to start this job. Error: An error occurred while
>   sending the request

I checked all the logs in the event viewer and there are no errors at all.
I also tried to re-install the agent and nothing seems to help.

My configuration process: 
[image]

**Edit:**
I found the problem. in the Team Foundation Administration Console the property of "Notification URL" was with invalid value of not existed server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. in the **Team Foundation Administration Console** the property of **"Notification URL"** was with **invalid value** of not existed server.

Answer (score 1):

If your build requires a specific capability, then the agent must have those.

> When a build is queued, the system sends the job only to agents that have the capabilities demanded by the build definition.

Check the build definition requirements and the agent offering: it is clearly described in the [Demands section](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general) of documentation.

Comment: It seems that i have all the capability required.
and know that normally when there is a missing capability the tfs popup a message about it

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the "Agent Pool Service Account" role.
2. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.

Adding a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: the user that run the agent have administrator permissions on the pool

Comment: The account need to be a "Agent Pool Service Account" role. Please double check it.

Comment: I dont have "Agent Pool Service Acount" the roles that i have are:
-Agent Queue Administrators
-Agent Queues Users

Comment: look at the screenshot that i added, there is no "Agent Pool Service Acount"

Comment: Please check my screenshot. You'are looking Agent Queues, not Agent Pools.

Comment: You right i was looking in a wrong place, but now i checked and i can see that the user that run the agent is in the correct role (Agent Pool Service Acount) any idea what else it can be?

Comment: Try to change a domain account which is a member of the Build Agent Service Accounts group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.

Comment: its already domain account and its in the  "Build Agent Service Accounts" group and also in "Agent Pool Service Account" role

Comment: Go to Task Manager and check whether your build agent service is running.

Comment: It is running as "vsoagent.apptfs.Agent-APPTFS"

Comment: Try to re-deploy a windows agent to see whether the issue persist: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v1-windows

Comment: There is another problem, when i try to download again the agent from the TFS i get an empty zip. do u know why? and how can i get a new agent?

Comment: ....So you deleted the agent on server? How about just re-run ConfigureAgent.cmd that you have?

Comment: You may share your configure process here. Also, have you upgraded your TFS 2015 to the latest edition TFS 2015.3?

Comment: I added my configuration process. and my TFS version is 2015.3

Comment: I couldn't find any issue according to the configuration process or your setting, did this build agent work before?

Comment: I found the problem tnx.