# Waiting for an available agent after trying to send a build to a new Build Server

Tags: tfs, build, agent

I just created a new Build server and added it to an existing Queue, I turned off the other agents in the queue so that this new build server would get the job. I sent a very simple .NET build but the build window says "Waiting for an available agent"
[image]

So I get it, I must have missed installing something on the build server. So when the job is submitted it's looking for an agent that can satisfy the "capabilities"  How can I see that what capabilities the job needs so I can see why it's stuck?

Comment: What **version** of TFS? Did you look at the agent logs?

Comment: TFS 2018, and I forgot about the Agent logs, I can check them.

Comment: @PatDelaney Is there any update for this issue? You could check the service and the account for running the agent.

Comment: So I am still trying to troubleshoot the issue. It would make it easier if I understood what happens with Queues.Currently I have a "test" queue that has 6 agents configured. Two if them are online. But the current Job  says Waiting for Enabled Agent, All possible agents are disabled. So I am going to guess that when an agent starts, it registers it's capabilities with the Queue. When a job comes in the Queue sends it to the first available agent that meets the capabilities. Right now it appears that none of them do. So what I want to see is what capabilities does the queued job need?

Comment: You could check the required capabilities for the build job in `Build Definition -> Options -> Demands`. But in TFS2018, there is no demand requirement by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if the agent capabilities couldn't meet the build demands, it will show the warning message at the build result or queue time.

For example:

[image: Warning]

You could try the following points to troubleshooting:

1. Navigate to **Local machine->Service** and check if the `Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent` is running on the TFS application tier server.

[image: Service]

You could start or restart this service.

2. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the `Agent Pool Service Account` role or `Project Collection Build Service Accounts` and the account is a domain account.

TFS2015 -> Agent Pool Service Account

TFS2017 TFS2018 ->Project Collection Build Service Accounts

Change another available account for agent service, restart the service.

3.Restart the whole TFS server and check if this do the trick. Need some time to wait.

Here is [another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610992/13464420) with the similar issue, you could refer to it.

Hope this helps.